# Laravel Migration - Model::find($id) return NULL but $id exists in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a curious problem with an really small migration.

Basic information: I currently have 3 instances of my Project: "Dev PC" (offline), "Dev Laptop" (offline) and "QS" (online)

So the last two days I wrote three different migrations. One which imports an JSON file with information about 6.000 Instances of the Model and writes those Models to the DB.

Second (which now is failing) should write some new data to those models and third one will rewrite some data.

If this is perfect should not be discussed here. That doesn't mind!

**So here is the Problem:** The second migration is failing on QS stage, but working on both Dev stages.

This was the first error

```
-sh-4.2$ /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php artisan migrate
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

 Do you really wish to run this command? (yes/no) [no]:
 > yes



  [ErrorException]
  Creating default object from empty value
```

Then I tried around a bit

```
-sh-4.2$ /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php artisan migrate --force --pretend -vvv
6219

  [ErrorException]
  Creating default object from empty value


Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/vhosts/database/migrations/2016_08_25_080129_import_old_adresses.php:28
 Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func() at /var/www/vhosts/vendor/sentry/sentry/lib/Raven/Breadcrumbs/ErrorHandler.php:36
 Raven_Breadcrumbs_ErrorHandler->handleError() at /var/www/vhosts/database/migrations/2016_08_25_080129_import_old_adresses.php:28
 ImportOldAdresses->up() at /var/www/vhosts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:319
 Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->Illuminate\Database\Migrations\{closure}() at /var/www/vhosts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:656
 Illuminate\Database\Connection->pretend() at /var/www/vhosts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:320
 Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->getQueries() at /var/www/vhosts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:295
 Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->pretendToRun() at /var/www/vhosts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:144
 Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->runUp() at /var/www/vhosts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:117
 Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->runMigrationList() at /var/www/vhosts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:86
 Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->run() at /var/www/vhosts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:77
 Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand->fire() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /var/www/vhosts/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:1257
 Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at /var/www/vhosts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:169
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at /var/www/vhosts/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:256
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/vhosts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:155
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at /var/www/vhosts/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:794
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/vhosts/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:186
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/vhosts/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/vhosts/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:107
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at /var/www/vhosts/artisan:36
```

And now I wanted to see the SQLs which were fired:

```
-sh-4.2$ /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php artisan migrate --force --pretend -vvv
array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "alter table `orders` add `oldName` varchar(255) not null, add `oldAdress` varchar(255) not null"
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 0.0
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `orders` where `orders`.`id` = ? limit 1"
    "bindings" => array:1 [
      0 => 6219
    ]
    "time" => 0.0
  ]
]
```

Now this is confusing because running the query `select * from` orders`where`orders`.`id `= 6219 limit 1` on DB directly results in `1 Entry, Query took 0.0005 seconds.`

So what could I do to debug Why laravel wont find my DB Entry?
Here is the migration:

string('oldName');
                $table->string('oldAdress');
            });
    
            // Load data to be imported.
            $oldOrders = json_decode(File::get('storage/olddata.json'), TRUE);
    
            // Update.
            foreach ($oldOrders as $rawOrder) {
                $order = \App\Order::find(intval($rawOrder['id'])); // Here's the crash right with the first iteration.
    
                $order->oldName   = $rawOrder['oldName'];
                $order->oldAdress = $rawOrder['oldAdress'];
    
                $order->save();
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down() {
            Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->dropColumn('oldName');
                $table->dropColumn('oldAdress');
            });
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I actually don't know what happend the first time as I ran the migration, but the further analyses answers theirselv. As of `--pretend` just simulates querys, the `Order::find($id)` won't return something. So the error occures.

I thought over and over and finaly run the same command as first time again (`/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php artisan migrate`) and it worked.